# How to get ng-model value inside custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've searched here on SO and tried the answers I found, but I can't seem to get the model value out of the ngModel of my custom directive.

[image]

Here's the directive

```js
/*
 *usage: <markdown ng:model="someModel.content"></markdown>
 */
breathingRoom.directive('markdown', function () {
    var nextId = 0;
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div class="pagedown-bootstrap-editor"></div>',
        link:function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

            var editorUniqueId = nextId++;
            element.html($('<div>' +
                '<div class="wmd-panel">' +
                '<div id="wmd-button-bar-' + editorUniqueId + '"></div>' +
                '<textarea class="wmd-input" id="wmd-input-' + editorUniqueId + '">{{modelValue()}}' +
                '</textarea>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div id="wmd-preview-' + editorUniqueId + '" class="wmd-panel wmd-preview"></div>' +
                '</div>'));

            var converter = new Markdown.Converter();

            var help = function () {
                // 2DO: add nice modal dialog
                alert("Do you need help?");
            };

            var editor = new Markdown.Editor(converter, "-" + editorUniqueId, {
                handler: help
            });

            editor.run();


            // local -> parent scope change (model)
            jQuery("#wmd-input-" + editorUniqueId).on('change', function () {
                var rawContent = $(this).val();
                ngModel.$setViewValue(rawContent);
                scope.$apply();
            });

            // parent scope -> local change
            scope.modelValue = function () {
                console.log('modelvalue - ', ngModel.$viewValue);
                return ngModel.$viewValue;
            };
        }
    };
});
```

And here's the HTML

```
<markdown ng-class="{error: (moduleForm.Description.$dirty && moduleForm.Description.$invalid) || (moduleForm.Description.$invalid && submitted)}"
          id="Description" 
          name="Description" 
          placeholder="Description" 
          ng-model="module.description" 
          required></markdown>
```

The problem here is that the output is simply

```
{{modelValue()}}
```

---

I also tried creating a private method

```
function getModelValue() {
    console.log(ngModel.$viewValue);
    return ngModel.$viewValue;
}
```

and then change the one template line to

```
'<textarea class="wmd-input" id="wmd-input-' + editorUniqueId + '">' + getModelValue() +
```

but then the output is

```
NaN
```

Where am I going wrong?

---

if it matters, here's the order of my scripts (not including vendor scripts)

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="directives/backButtonDirective.js"></script>
<script src="directives/bootstrapSwitchDirective.js"></script>
<script src="directives/markdownDirective.js"></script>
<script src="directives/trackActiveDirective.js"></script>
<script src="services/alertService.js"></script>
<script src="services/roleService.js"></script>
<script src="services/moduleService.js"></script>
<script src="services/changePasswordService.js"></script>
<script src="services/userService.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/usersController.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/userController.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/moduleController.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/modulesController.js"></script>
```

Comment: The value is `{{modelValue()}}` because you are simply passing this as a string when you build your HTML. You're not actually resolving this value anywhere. Why don't you make it part of your template instead?

Comment: Not sure how that would look. @BenFoster. In the second part of my question, I tried using a method, but it's return value is `NaN`.

Comment: Hopefully my updated answer is closer to what you are hoping to achieve.

Answer (score 14):

The HTML your inserting isn't getting compiled.  It's easiest just to move it into your template, or investigate using ng-transclude.  Here's an example of moving it into your template.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cidTZLY9GpESMvCcHKBU?p=preview)

```
breathingRoom.directive('markdown', function () {
    var nextId = 0;
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div class="pagedown-bootstrap-editor"><div class="wmd-panel">' +
                '<div id="wmd-button-bar-{{editorUniqueId}}"></div>' +
                '<textarea class="wmd-input" id="wmd-input-{{editorUniqueId}}">{{modelValue()}}' +
                '</textarea>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div id="wmd-preview-{{editorUniqueId}}" class="wmd-panel wmd-preview"></div>' +
                '</div></div>',
        link:function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

            scope.editorUniqueId = nextId++;

            // parent scope -> local change
            scope.modelValue = function () {
                console.log('modelvalue - ' + ngModel.$viewValue);
                return ngModel.$viewValue;
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: +1 for not just creating an attribute called ngModel, which is deceptive since it isn't an ngModel directive object (access to .$viewValue, .$formatters, etc.)

Answer (score 10):

You weren't actually resolving your model as the `{{modelValue()}}` expression was just part of the HTML string your were building in the link function.

You should move the editor markup to the `template` so that you can bind to `ng-model`.

Assuming the goal is to create the necessary HTML markup for the Markdown Editor and then show the preview of the *converted* markdown I would split this into two roles:

1. A directive for the custom markup
2. A filter for actually converting the value to markdown:

Markup:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
    <h3>Markdown editor</h3>
    <markdown-editor ng-model="markdown"></markdown-editor>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.filter('markdown', function () {
    return function (input) {
        return input.toUpperCase(); // this is where you'd convert your markdown
    };
});

app.directive('markdownEditor', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            ngModel: "="
        },
        template:
            '<div>' +
            '<textarea ng-model="ngModel"></textarea>' +
            '<div class="preview">{{ ngModel | markdown }}</div>' +
            '</div>'
    };
});

app.controller('DemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.markdown = "**hello world**";
});
```

The `=` scope sets up a two way binding on the property passed to `ng-model` and `{{ ngModel | markdown }}` pipes the value of `ngModel` to the `markdown` filter.

http://jsfiddle.net/benfosterdev/jY3ZK/

Comment: Thanks for all your help. unfortunately the reason it can't live in a template is because the pagedown library can't properly handle the `editorUniqueId` if it's in a template. I ended up doing a bunch of searching, and came up with this. https://github.com/programmieraffe/angular-editors/blob/master/editors/pagedown-bootstrap/directive.js

Comment: I think you could also change the name on the newly created isolated scope by doing this `scope: {newName: '=ngModel'}`

Answer (score 3):

Look at angular's [parse](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse) service. It enables you get and set the value of property referenced in ng-model.

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    var getter = $parse(attrs.ngModel);
    var setter = getter.assign;
    var value = getter(scope);
    setter(scope, 'newValue');
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Kind Lady, have a  (or a ☕ if you want). For the record, this stuff actually works and I believe it is the "Angular way". It is clean, it clearly states intent, and it works without the programmer having any knowledge on what is ngModel doing in the background. +10 if I could!

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is:

**If ngModel variable is on the top level of the scope**

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    if (attrs.ngModel) {
        var myModelReference = scope[attrs.ngModel];
    }
}
```

**If ngModel refers to a property deeply nested on the scope (best way)**

(so, for `scope.prop1.prop2` , `attrs.ngModel` will be "`prop1.prop2`"), and since you can't just look up `scope['prop1.prop2']`, you need to dig in by converting the string key to actual nested keys.

For this I recommend Lodash `_.get()` function

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    if (attrs.ngModel) {
        var myModelReference = _.get(scope, attrs.ngModel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Angular's $parse service can be used instead of _.get().