# Use ng-model in directive and controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to access in Directive the ng-model that is linked to the Controller?

```
<input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.valuelist.value" />
```

Controller:

```
ctrl.valuelist.value = 'initial value';
```

In directive:

```
function Directive($window) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
    },
    controller: 'ctrl as ctrl',
    link: function(scope, elt, attrs){
      // something like this:

      scope.valuelist.value = 'New value';


    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get ng-model value inside custom directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22237265/how-to-get-ng-model-value-inside-custom-directive)

Comment: also check [Get value from ngModel in custom directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060733)

Comment: Not sure, they're not the same question.

Comment: @Nima Please, put full example -- currently not clear from what and where you want to access what).

Comment: Thanks just updated

Comment: It is not clear how your directive is being used, the HTML snippet doesn't contain any custom tags, how is the directive related to the HTML snipped that you have provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function Directive($window) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      ngModel: '=' //<----- access to the model by this
    },
    controller: 'ctrl as ctrl',
    link: function(scope, elt, attrs){
      // something like this:

      scope.ngModel = 'New value';


    } 
  };
}
```

I'm a pleb, so be kind.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass attributes to your directive by two way('=') this mean when you make change from directive will reflect in controller as well

```
function Directive($window) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
         list: '='
    },
    controller: 'ctrl as ctrl',
    link: function(scope, elt, attrs){
      // something like this:

      scope.list.value = 'New value';


    }
  };
}
```

And you must pass **valuelist** to your directive example:

```
<directive list='valuelist'></directive>
```