# How to pass controller data to a custom directive in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom directive in AngularJS and I want to pass a variable to it from my controller.

#### Controller:

```
angular.
    module('orderOverview').
    component('orderOverview', {
        templateUrl: 'home-page/order-overview/order-overview.template.html',
        controller: ['Orders',
            function ControllerFunction(Orders) {
        var self = this;

        // Order Info
        Orders.getOverview().$promise.then(function(data) {
          self.LineItems = data;
        });
        // Order Info
      }
    ]
  });
```

#### Directive

```
angular.
    module('myApp').
    directive('gvInitializeOrderStatus', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        field: '@',
        myData: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, element) {
        console.log('field:', scope.field);
        console.log('data:', scope.myData);
      }
    }
    });
```

#### HTML

```
<div gv-initialize-order-status field="InquiryDone" myData="$ctrl.LineItems">
    <span class="tooltiptext">Inquiry</span>
</div>
```

When I load the page, `field` logs fine, however `data` is undefined.

I've tried this a lot of ways, but this is how it should work in my mind if it gives you any idea of what I'm thinking of.

At another point in the same template I pass `ng-repeat` data to a directive just fine, but in this case I specifically don't want to `ng-repeat`

#### ng-repeat HTML that successfully passed data

```
<li ng-repeat="lineItem in $ctrl.LineItems">
    <div class="status-circle" 
         ng-click="toggleCircle($event, lineItem, 'InquiryDone')"
         field="InquiryDone" item="lineItem" gv-initialize-statuses>
        <span class="tooltiptext">Inquiry</span>
    </div>
</li>
```

In my other directive, `gv-initialize-statuses`, I use the same concept in my `scope` object and have something like `scope: { 'field': '=' }` and it works just fine.

How can I accomplish this without using ng-repeat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found an answer that works when I was reading about $compile in the docs. I realized you can get interpolated attribute values, so I removed the `myData` field from the scope object and instead accessed the value through the `attrs` object, like so.

#### Directive

```
angular.
    module('myApp').
    directive('gvInitializeOrderStatus', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        field: '@'
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log('field:', scope.field);
        console.log('attrs:', attrs);
        attrs.$observe('lineItems', function(value) {
          console.log(value);
        })
      }
    }
    });
```

#### HTML

```
<div gv-initialize-order-status field="InquiryDone" lineItems="{{$ctrl.LineItems}}">
     <span class="tooltiptext">Inquiry</span>
</div>
```

Notice the added `{{ }}` to the lineItems attribute. The `attrs.$observe` block lets me get notices of changes to the value, as well.

Comment: If that works for you, then get rid of the isolate scope entirely and use `attrs.field` for the `field` attribute. Then you have an attribute directive that plays nicely with other attribute directives.

Answer (score 1):

## Two-way binding with `=` should be avoided

The directive needs to use $watch in the link function:

```
app.directive('gvInitializeOrderStatus', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        field: '@',
        ̶m̶y̶D̶a̶t̶a̶:̶ ̶'̶=̶'̶
        myData: '<'
      },
      link: function(scope, element) {
        console.log('field:', scope.field);
        console.log('data:', scope.myData);
        scope.$watch('myData', function(value) {
            console.log('data:', scope.myData);
        });
      }
    }
});
```

Directives such as `ng-repeat` automatically use a watcher.

Also for performance reasons, two-way binding with `=` should be avoided. One-way binding with `<` is more efficient.

---

For more efficient code, use the [`$onChanges` life-cycle hook](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks)  in the controller:

```
app.directive('gvInitializeOrderStatus', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        field: '@',
        ̶m̶y̶D̶a̶t̶a̶:̶ ̶'̶=̶'̶
        myData: '<'
      },
      bindToController: true,
      controllerAs: "$ctrl",
      controller: function() {
        console.log('field:', this.field);
        console.log('data:', this.myData);
        this.$onChanges = function(changes) {
            if (changes.myData)
                console.log('data:', changes.myData.currentValue);
            };
        });
      }
    }
});
```

Doing so will make the code more efficient and the migration to Angular 2+ easier.

---

There are different levels of watch:

[image]

The `ng-repeat` directive actually uses [$watchCollection](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchCollection).

The directive may need to use the [`$doCheck` Life-Cycle hook](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks).

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Scope `$watch` Depths](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-watch-depths)
- [AngularJs 1.5 - Component does not support Watchers, what is the work around?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35535336/5535245)
- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Component-based application architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture)

Comment: I like the tip about the one way binding, but this actually isn't a promise issue. I was playing around and found without ng-repeat I couldn't even pass a variable such as `self.testVar = 400`. I tried both of these solutions, but myData was still undefined.

Comment: The next step is to create a [PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I will set a reminder to try this later, for learning's sake. However, I found a working solution that I just put up and I'll have to keep going for now.

Answer (score 0):

Do this if you just want the data in your directive

```
Orders.getOverview().$promise.then(function(data) {
          self.LineItems = data;
          $rootScope.$broadcast('myData', data);
        });
```

And in your directive just catch this event with callback function

```
$scope.$on('myData', function(event, args) {

    var anyThing = args;
    // do what you want to do
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `$promise`.

`self.LineItems` is not ready when the directive get active. That's why data is `undefined`.

Maybe `ng-if` could helps you:

```
<div ng-if="$ctrl.LineItems" gv-initialize-order-status field="InquiryDone" myData="$ctrl.LineItems">
    <span class="tooltiptext">Inquiry</span>
</div>
```

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

in directive

```
angular.
module('myApp').
directive('gvInitializeOrderStatus', function() {
return {
  scope: {
    field: '@',
    ngModel: '='     // <- access data with this (ngModel to ng-model in view)
  },
  link: function(scope, element) {
    console.log('field:', scope.field);
    console.log('data:', scope.ngModel);
  }
}
});
```

in view

```
<div gv-initialize-order-status field="InquiryDone" ng-model="$ctrl.LineItems">
  <span class="tooltiptext">Inquiry</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of a duplicate by the way : [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50043159/use-ng-model-in-directive-and-controller/50045176#50045176)

Comment: The `ng-model` attribute instantiates the [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController). Unless you intend to turn the `<div>` element into a form control, that name should be avoided.